# Does anyone know the location of this login hotmail background?

Tags: where-on-earth, nature-and-wildlife, lock-screens

Does anyone know the location of this login hotmail background ?[image]

Answer (score 7):

Rio de Janeiro, Brazil. Likely taken from somewhere near the [Christ the Redeemer statue.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_the_Redeemer_(statue))

Answer (score 5):

Rio de Janeiro, Brazil.

In the background you can see [Pão de Açúcar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugarloaf_Mountain) and Botafogo.

Answer (score 3):

That's Rio de Janeiro.

Do a google image search and it should pop right up: [Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=rio%20de%20janeiro&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ3rCsy-TaAhVQyYMKHSnUDo4Q_AUIDCgD&biw=1920&bih=950)